# Determine MessageBoxIcon Based on ComboBox

Tags: c#, messagebox

I want to combine a ComboBox's value and a MessageBoxIcon. I want it (basically) to do this:

```
MessageBox.Show("Text", "Text", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.ComboBox.Value.ToString());
```

Is this possible? It doesn't have to be done in one line. The text will be either "Warning" or "Error".

Comment: You mean you want to select a `MessageBoxIcon` type based on ComboBox text?

Comment: Yes, but without doing an if statement for every option in the ComboBox. The text will be exactly what you need if you were to write it out yourself.

Comment: Untested but I have seen people use the + symbol to combine message box types so like if you used the vbCritical + vbYesNo it should work. I dont think that would work the way you are doing it now.

Comment: It might be better to edit your question title to **Determine MessageBoxIcon Based on ComboBox**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Enum.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx) method:

```
MessageBox.Show("Text", "Text", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
(MessageBoxIcon)Enum.Parse(typeof(MessageBoxIcon), ComboBox.Text.ToString());
```

Comment: Rename `ComboBox` properly according to what name the control has in your project.